# How to make module send a message from another module OMNet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

For example I have 2 simple modules sM1 and sM2, and now I want to sM2 make sM1 schedule a message. I tried with that code but it doesn't work

```html
// this is the sM2
cSimpleModule *sM1  = check_and_cast<cSimpleModule *> (getModuleByPath("network.module.sM1"));
cMessage *Return = new cMessage("BAM");
sM1->scheduleAt(simTime(), Return);
```

During the simulation OMNet++ tell me about Enter_Method or something like that. How to fix that please?.

Comment: This code wouldn't make any sense. Since when does your object sM1 provide the scheduleAt() method? You can only run public methods of said object...

So (for example) send a message from sM2 to sM1 which sM1 then evaluates and afterwards sM1 schedules the message. Or make a public method for sM1/2 that does this message scheduling that you like and call it.

Comment: I'll try the method of public function since that i don't want sM2 send a message to sM1